# Are negative lookbehind in regex searches possible in Geany?

Tags: regex, pcre, geany, negative-lookbehind

[Geany's documentation on negative assertions](http://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-regex-syntax.html#idp5790880) makes it look like they're possible.

For reference, this works and gives me results:

```
pcregrep -r "(?<!= )function\(" src/main-js/
```

But the same regex, or *any regex with a negative lookbehind*, gives me no result when launched from Geany (v 1.24.1)

[image]

Where is the problem? Is the documentation wrong?

**Precision:** the topic **isn't** about how to avoid doing a negative look behind, but about how to do any standard [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) negative look behind.

Comment: try `(?<!=\s)function\(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got support from the Geany developers on [Freenode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenode), and it was very helpful. Here is what they told me:

> The documented RE syntax only applies to the RE engine directly used by
> Geany (e.g. in Find), but the Find in Files features calls the grep tool
> (as configured in preferences->tools->grep), which has its own syntax.
> For GNU grep, you can add "-P" to the "Extra options" field in the
> dialog

However, after you tried it, you had this error:

> /bin/grep: conflicting matchers specified

... to which I was told this was a Geany bug. Geany calls `grep -E`, and `-P` is not compatible with it.

Your only workaround is to have a shell script calling [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) with `-P` instead of `-E`, and use this script. You should be able to configure the grep tool to call in Geany preferences.

An example of said shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

matchopts=$(echo "$1" | tr E P)
shift

exec grep $matchopts "$@"
```

Geany uses [either `-F` or `-E`](https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/826f6516d36ec7a7bed35116fda32d42449c1e5d/src/search.c#L1563-L1566) (these are the only available engines in POSIX grep) for grep, hence why you can't pass `-P`.

I've reported [the bug](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/443) to the Geany developers.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to avoid the negative lookbehind assertion… but it's a lot uglier:

```
(^.?|[^=] |=[^ ]|[^=][^ ])function
```